# drupal logout when logout from phpbb

Tags: drupal, logout, phpbb

I am trying to synchronize session from drupal to phpbb and I am able to login in both drupal/phpbb when I login with drupal. Same as when I logout with drupal it automatically logout with phpbb.

But I want two way synchronization. When I logout from phpbb it should automatically lougout from drupal also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some code and destroy the Drupal session/cookie when you log out from PHPbb. There is no otherway.

Comment: You can also call www.yoursite.com/users/logout using ajax.